# JAVA IO, Read values from txt file and send to method params

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that will perform a calculation from a text file input.

The text file contains the following columns: amount1, amount2, amount3

I have a method named Calculate which takes in these parameters and does the calculation and subsequent actions.

I also have a main method as follows, but am experiencing troubles in getting the tokens into the Calculate mthod parametsrs,
please refer to code below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class myProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

    File file = new File( "data.txt");
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(file);
    while (infile.hasNext() ){
        String str = infile.nextLine();     
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, ", ");

        // I want to get the output of each of the tokens into the parameters of my Calculate class here
    }
    infile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a csv file so better use a CSVReader rather than implementing of your own. [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is one of the available choice. Here is sample to read a csv file:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
   String amount1 = nextLine[0];
   String amount2 = nextLine[1];
   String amount3 = nextLine[2];
   // yourMethod(amount1,amount2,amount3);
}
```

Comment: How would you send them as method parameters as opposed to printing?